# Quartic Quasi-Discriminant

Tags: polynomials

I'm trying to find a condition on a, b and c for the quartic $P(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx+c$ to have a triple root.

Using the Multiple Root Theorem, it's easy to show that if it has a triple root, it must be $\alpha=-\frac{a}{2}$.

So the usual method of finding the condition is to substitute this back into the original polynomial. In other words, $P\left ( -\frac{a}{2} \right )=0$ should yield the (necessary?) condition for the polynomial to have a triple root.

After some computation, I get

- $a^4+8ab=16c \qquad (1)$

Here is where I come across issues.

In order to check that this actually works, I set $a=1, b=1$ and found $c=\frac{9}{16}$, which does NOT have a triple root from the graphing calculator.

My thought process then was "Oh! It must be because all triple roots must also be double roots as well, so perhaps I need to substitute $x=-\frac{a}{2}$ back into $P'(x)$ to get a second condition that must be satisfied!"

So I worked with

$P'\left ( -\frac{a}{2} \right )=0 $ to get

- $a^3+4b=0 \qquad (2)$

My thought process afterwards was "Okay, so if I find a,b,c satisfying both (1) AND (2), then that should yield a polynomial with a triple root!"

I set $a=2$, which gave me $b=-2$ using (2) which then using (1) yielded $c=-1$. So this triplet should satisfy both conditions (1) and (2).

But the graph does not have a triple root unfortunately.

What is going on? Is it perhaps to do with the fact that the conditions are necessary, but not sufficient?

Comment: From the condition $P'''(x)=0$ I get $x = -a/4$.

Comment: @MartinG $P''(\alpha)=0$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't $P'''(x)=0$ the condition for a root of multiplicity 4?

Comment: I have found that $x^4+2x^3-2x-1=(x-1)(x+1)^3$. So if $a=2$, you have a triple root.

Comment: Okay, I have identified that I simply typed the equation incorrectly into the calculator.

In that case, why does a triplet (a,b,c) satisfying (1) not yield a triple root, whereas (a,b,c) satisfying (1) AND (2) work?

For example, (2,-2,-1) works as it's derived from (1) and (2), whereas (1,1,9/16) doesn't work, and it's derived purely from (1).

Comment: A triple root requires both P''(0) (contrary to my earlier comment!) and P'(0). This becomes clear if you sketch a graph.

Comment: Ah yes! Silly me. I had forgotten that:

P''(k)=0 ---> potential inflexion point.

P'(k)=0 ---> potential horizontal inflexion point.

P(k)=0 ---> lies on the x axis.

Comment: A long long time after this question has been issued, I propose a new look on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a triple root at $x$ when $P(x)=0\land P'(x)=0\land P''(x)$ simultaneously.

$$x^4+ax^3+bx+c=0\\4x^3+3ax^2+b=0\\12x^2+6ax=0.$$

An obvious solution is $x=0$, with $b=c=0$ and arbitrary $a$. There is another for $x=-\dfrac a2$.

---

> $$x=-\frac a2,b=-\frac{a^3}4,c=-\frac{a^4}{16}.$$

Comment: You leave condition $x=-\frac{a}{2}$ as it is, hopefuly for encouraging the OP to work out this case. I have tried, using another characterization of a triple root, to proceed till the end ; I have been rather surprized by the nice form taken by the general case (see my solution).

Comment: @JeanMarie: I have added the coefficients. Our solutions coincide.

Answer (score 0):

The case of a root that is **at least** double is well-known and characterized by the anihilation of the discriminant.

Let us consider the specific case where there is exactly a triple root $t$, the other root $s$ being simple. 
$$x^4+ax^3+bx+c
 =  (x-s)(x-t)^3\ \ \text{for certain} \  s, t, \ s \neq t \tag{1}$$

This case is amenable to something rather interesting .

Expanding the RHS of (1) and identifying similar coefficients, we obtain the system :

$$\begin{cases}a + 3t + s&=&0 \ \ \ \ \ (a)\\
     3t(t+s)&=&0 \ \ \ \ \ (b)\\
     t^3 +3st^2 + b&=&0 \ \ \ \ \ (c)\\
     st^3 - c&=&0 \ \ \ \ \ (d)
\end{cases}$$

Condition (b) permit to split the issue into two subcases :

- If $t=0$, one obtains $b=c=0$ and $s=-a$, whence the first family of solutions, polynomials

$$P_a(x)=x^4-ax^3=x^3(x-a)$$

which indeed have $0$ as a triple root and $a \neq 0$ as the simple root.

- If $t \neq 0$, condition (b) gives $s=-t$. Plugging this expression of $s$ into (a),(c) and (d) finally gives the second family of solutions :

$$Q_t(x)=x^4-2tx^3+2t^3x-t^4=(x+t)(x-t)^3$$

once again depending on a single parameter ($t \neq 0$).

Here is a graphical representation of some polynomials $Q_t$ for $t=-4...4 \ \ (t \neq 0)$ :

[image]

*Fig. 1.  Graphical representation of different polynomials $Q_t$. For $t = -2$, one gets the curve in dark red with roots in $t=-2$ (triple root) and in $s=2$ (simple root).*